# Validar Contraseña del Login WPF

Tags: visual-studio

Quisiera pedirles su ayuda para poder resolver un problema que tengo.
Realice la ventana login que funcionara todo bien, valida que el usuario y la contraseña estén en lo correcto y abra el proyecto, pero no distingue que la contraseña este con mayúscula o minúscula.
Ya sea que la escriba con mayúscula o minúscula ingresa igual.

Este es el boton aceptar:

```
    private async void BtnAceptar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtUsuario.Text.Trim() == string.Empty)
        {
            await this.ShowMessageAsync("Error:",
                 string.Format("Usuario en blanco favor ingresar"));             
            txtUsuario.Focus();
        }
        else
        {
            if (txtContrasenna.Password.Trim() == string.Empty)
            {
                await this.ShowMessageAsync("Error:",
                    string.Format("Contraseña en blanco favor ingresar"));
                txtContrasenna.Focus();
            }
            else
            {
                Usuario usuario = new Usuario(txtUsuario.Text, txtContrasenna.Password);
                if (usuario.Leer())
                {
                    
                    await this.ShowMessageAsync("Mensaje:",
                        string.Format("Hola {0}, bienvenido a Fast Food Restaurant", txtUsuario.Text));
                    this.Hide();
                    MainWindow menu = new MainWindow();
                    menu.Closed += (s, args) => this.Close();
                    menu.ShowDialog();
                    Limpiar();

                }
                else
                {
                    await this.ShowMessageAsync("Error:",
                        string.Format("Usuario o Contraseña incorrectos"));
                    Limpiar();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Este es el crud para la conexión:

```
    public bool Leer()
    {
        try
        {
            Datos.Usuarios sesion = Conexion.Con.Usuarios.First(pp => pp.ContraB == Contrasenna);

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Les agradezco un montón por la ayuda.
Que tengan una excelente semana.

Comment: que base de datos utilizas?

Comment: SQL Server
Gracias

Comment: Prueba a cambiar el ‘ = ‘ por el ‘ equals ‘ , donde haces la comparación de lo que escribe el usuario y lo que está en tu base de datos.

Answer (score 0):

Por defecto SQL Server es case insensitive, por lo que puedes tener bases de datos o sus tablas con esta condición, pero también SQL Server da la posibilidad de que una base de datos o tabla especifica pueda ser case sensitive.

Para poder comprobar esto, primero que nada debes realizar la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT collation_name
FROM sys.databases
WHERE name = 'nombre_de_tu_bd';
```

Donde permite comprobar si tu base de datos es o no case sensitive, deberías obtener una salida similar a esta:

```
SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

Donde el valor entre **CP1_** y **_AS** nos indica la configuración.

**CI = Case Insensitive,
CS = Case Sensitive**

Para poder actualizarlo es necesario ejecutar la siguiente sentencia:

```
ALTER DATABASE nombre_de_tu_bd
   COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS;
```

**EDIT**

Investigando otro poco, el realizar el cambio en la base de datos, solo afectara a los nuevos objetos que se creen, por lo que los existentes se mantendrán, para poder cambiarlos se debe realizar un alter table y modificar la tabla o modificar la columna. Te dejo la sentencia que verifica y modifica la columna

**Verifica**

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, COLLATION_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Mi_tabla' 
AND COLUMN_NAME = 'Columna_tabla' AND CHARACTER_SET_NAME IS NOT NULL;
```

**Modifica**

```
    ALTER TABLE dbo.nombre_tabla 
    ALTER COLUMN nombre_columna VARCHAR(50) 
    COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC_UTF8; -- aquí debes colocar el que corresponda
```

Otra forma que vi, es la de establecer este parámetro en el propio select, por ejemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM tabla_usuarios 
WHERE user='usuario' and pass='pass' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS;
```

Actualizo los links que utilice de referencia:

- Modificar COLLATE base de datos [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/set-or-change-the-database-collation?view=sql-server-ver15).
- Modificar COLLATE de columnas [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/set-or-change-the-column-collation?view=sql-server-ver15).
- Verificar case sensitive [link](https://www.webucator.com/how-to/how-check-case-sensitivity-sql-server.cfm).

Con todo esto verificado y en caso de que tu base de datos sea case insensitive, al configurarla, ya debería poder validar entre mayúsculas y minúsculas en tu login.

Comment: Lo valide y altere al tabla pero aún el login sigue tomando tanto minúsculas como mayúsculas como correctas e ingresa al software.

Comment: Por lo que vi, las tablas que ya fueron definidas por el usuario no cambian y deben ser modificadas con un **alter table** voy a editar la respuesta.

Comment: edite la respuesta, espero sea lo que te pueda ayudar o por ultimo que te pueda guiar en tu problema.